# Gridsome + AWS Amplify - Importing Event Bus breaks Logout Button Component

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, authentication, aws-amplify, gridsome

I have successfully integrated AWS Amplify's Auth UI functionality and components with Gridsome for simple login/logout functionality but when I try to access the the Amplify Event Bus with

`import { AmplifyEventBus } from "aws-amplify-vue"`

I get the error:

`Error in mounted hook (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Logger' of undefined"`

I have found a similar issue [on the github post](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2401) and adding the suggested

```
Vue.prototype.$Amplify = Amplify;
```

does remove the warning but the Auth UI Logout component will no longer show up. I can Login but the Logout button does not show up. I do not understand why accessing the event bus would necessitate me adding Amplify to the Vue prototype when the UI components are already working without it AND why even if I do add it the components still do not appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AmplifyEventBus` has been discontinued, so is now considered `Legacy`

Instead, use `Hub.listen`, like this:

```
<script>
import { Hub } from 'aws-amplify'

export default {
  mounted() {
    Hub.listen('auth', (info) => {
      console.log('auth event:', info)
    })
  },
}
</script>
```

Logger can also be imported in the same way, like:

```
import { Hub, Logger } from 'aws-amplify'
```